# xpad notes remain pasted at the time of startup

Tags: startup

How can I add the Xpad in my startup programs so that they remain pasted on my desktop (Ubuntu 13.10) always? However Xpad is working fine but it doesn't start at the booting of the machine and I want Xpad to automatically load and notes be pasted on the desktop always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Dash and type Startup Applications. Click on the icon to open the window.

In the command field, type `xpad`. In the other fields you may enter whatever you want. 
The command field requires you to enter the command that will initiate the application from your terminal which is `xpad` in this case.

Name field is any custom name for the application that you want. You may leave the description empty if you want.